# POST request body undefined with firestore query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following firebase cloud function that check if the username exists in any firestore doc. I used POST request on client side with Context-Type: application/JSON

```
exports.login = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    console.log(request.body);
    let query = admin.firestore().collection("admin").where("username", "==", request.body.username);
    query.get().then(snapshot => {
        let loginStatus = false;
        if (snapshot.length > 0) loginStatus= true;
        response.send(loginStatus);
        return;
    }).catch();
    response.send(<NOT_IMPORTANT>);
})
```

if I commented `let query = admin...`, I can log `request.body` properly. But with that line exists, request.body becomes undefined, and I can't use it in query. If I hardcode request.body.username to "123" in query, it also works fine and return corresponding docs. Any thing I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is likely due to the fact that you are using an asynchronous command, by time your `.get()` is fully evaluated, your `response.send(<NOT_IMPORTANT>)` has already fired, and has closed that req/res.

You need to remove the `response.send(<NOT_IMPORTANT>);` from the end of your function. Give your `.get()` query time to run.

Also related to the topic... While your database is small, it's probably not an issue... but I recommend you follow [best practices to ensure your cloud function has enough time to run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) by returning your promise. Those docs include the explanation:

> By returning the result of `.set()`, your function is guaranteed to keep running until the asynchronous work of writing the string to the database is fully completed
>
> ```
> exports.hello = functions.database.ref('/hello').onWrite(event => {
>     // set() returns a promise. We keep the function alive by returning it.
>     return event.data.ref.set('world!').then(() => {
>         console.log('Write succeeded!');
>     });
> });
> ```

So what I'm suggesting is:

```
exports.login = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    let query = admin.firestore().collection("admin").where("username", "==", request.body.username);
    return query.get().then(snapshot => {
        let loginStatus = false;
        if (snapshot.length > 0) loginStatus= true;
        response.send(loginStatus);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

Comment: I think you are correct. I may try that at some time as now I have switched to express.js and it is working.